# Can't connect C# WinForm to an Online DataBase

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0, database-connection

I am using the below code for connecting to SQL Server on 2 different laptops and is working only on just one. On the other one, it shows up the next error:

```
Application.exe Error: 0 : Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll
The program '[3928] Application.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I want to mention that I have set `%` on `Manage Access Hosts`. So I can't figure out why it is not working on the other laptop.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
   private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connString = $"SERVER=zzz; PORT=3306; DATABASE=DB_name; UID=usr; PASSWORD=password;";
            conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                conn.Close();
                conexiune = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Check Internet Connection");
            }
        }

}
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: **Side Note:** You really shouldn't be exposing the DB directly to the app, you should have a service your application can reach out to that communicates to the DB for you.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Can you tell me how should I create that service? How can I google it?

Comment: _"Can you tell me how should I create that service?"_ That's way beyond what SO can do. There are many ways to set up a Data Service. You could host a REST API, a gRPC Service, ... the point is, you "abstract away" your actual DB from the front end. So, in that aspect, @Çöđěxěŕ's advice is not bad advice, **but** if there is a connectivity problem with one of your machines to the remote DB, it wouldn't surprise me if it also had a problem with a service connection. Maybe check network connectivity first. Can your faulting machine reach the DB machine?